# Prestashop img folder is too big (almost 40GB)

Tags: image, size, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop store which is getting bigger and bigger, around 40 GB. Recently I have realized that the folder img/ is taking around 95% of disk space. After counting my products and average number of images per product and average size per image I am sure it should not exceed 5GB. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of things you can try:

1. Set write permission on folders and files in img/* directory. It can be
   done on your hosting cPanel or by direct ssh access, or any other
   way you are comfortable with.
2. In your prestashop backoffice, go to Preference -> Images. Check if
   "Generate high resolution images" option is active. If so, you can
   disable it, as it takes very huge space (doubles images folder size)
   and it does not help that much as people use laptops and
   mobile phones to browse online stores nowadays.
3. On the same page, at the bottom, Regenerate thumbnails. It will
   clear old images and create new ones.

I believe after following these steps you should be able to save a lot of space.

Also, check prestashop addons for image cleaning modules. For example: http://addons.prestashop.com/en/22308-redundant-image-cleaner.html

This module will help you to delete images that are no longer used.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed instructions.

Comment: @Developer another advice - check on same tab if all image types, like "thumbnail_default" etc. really used in your theme. Just Prestashop pre-generate all these images and keep it on drive